# Site App Permissions, re-add erased permission

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I accidentally erased Workflow from Site App Permission page...
Then when I try to deactivate and reactivate the feature, SharePoint don't want to add the line anymore

Comment: what version and edition of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint Server 2013